# Moving Drupal website to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: drupal, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-platform

I build Bitnami WordPress websites on the Google Cloud Platform. For one of my latest projects, the client has asked if I can move their previous Drupal website also to the Google Cloud so that they can use this as a backup for when they need to check old archives etc. I quickly deployed a Bitnami Drupal instance and this would be an easy process.. I was wrong. I am battling to find any good info regarding importing website data into Drupal.

I was provided with a .SQL and .GZ file from the previous host via FTP, and I have set up SSH access to PhpMyAdmin. Does anyone possibly have any tips or know of any good guides for how I can import this data into my new Drupal location?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architecture of Drupal 7 and 8 are really different, so you need to be very careful about this: you should migrate D7 to D7, D8 to D8.
For both D7 and D8, be sure to have installed an updated version to latest releases, to avoid to be vulnerable by recent "drupalgeddon 2 and 3" security issues.

Then, you should:

- Copy the whole Drupal code: core, modules, themes
- Copy the files and static assets directory
- Create the empty database using Drupal interface wizard
- Import your SQL data

I suggest to you to learn to use command line tools like Drush (it should be preinstalled in the Bitnami app), to import the DB, to set/unset maintenance mode, to clear the Drupal cache (it's a recurrent operation in Drupal) and other very useful commands.

Some useful links:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/drupal/

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/backing-up-and-migrating-a-site/migrating-a-site

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For further reference, the guys at Bitnami went a bit more in-depth (I was very new to Drupal at this stage) as there were also permission commands required. The full thread can be located here - https://community.bitnami.com/t/importing-a-sql-and-gz-back-up-into-drupal/57501